# Change marginLeft to child div inside a scrolling parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to place a `position: absolute` div inside a scrolling div and make it stay on the left when scrolling left or right. This is because I want the div to move like one unit (when scrolling left, right, top, bottom). It's working great on screen that lower then 2K but on HD screens (ie. 2k, 3k, 4k...) the child div is jumping around and looks bad.

Is there a better way to do it? What change should I make to the CSS for HD screens?

```
#parent {    
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#child {    
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$("#parent").on('scroll', function (event) {
     $("#child")[0].style.marginLeft = this.scrollLeft+"px";
});
```

Comment: Why don't you make the div a fixed position instead of absolute? There is no need to set the margin every time?!

Comment: I made you an example in my answer for this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `css` function to set the value. And use the parent element as jQuery object to use `scrollLeft()` function:

```
$("#parent").on("scroll", function() {
    $("#child").css("margin-left", $(this).scrollLeft() + "px");
});
```

But I would not use jQuery for this at all. Why not use a `fixed` position in css for this? [Like in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gm0y9w99/3/). It should not flicker on any screen.

Comment: Because `$("#child")` is an jQuery object and not plain js. If you want to, you have to select the dom element, than you can use is the js-way: `$("#child")[0].style.marginLeft = '123px';`.

Comment: you are right I forgot to put the [0] in my example.Thank You!:)

Comment: Okay, change it to jQurey's `.scrollLeft()` too, because `scrollLeft` is not completly supported.

Comment: The fixed div is show on the scroller when the height are the same. Is there a way to make the scroller on top of the child div ?